# Subtracting Expressions (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have 2 expressions to fill in the column for the current amount and prior amount:

Current Amount: `=IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!AP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, "")`

Prior Amount: `=IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!PRAP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, "")`

What I need to is complete a 3rd column (called "Diff) by subtracting the value in the prior amount field from the value in the current amount field.

I tried to use the following expression that subtracts 1 from the other to get the difference:

```
=(=IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!AP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, 0)) – (=IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!PRAP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, 0))
```

However, I get the following errorm message:

```
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox6.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30037] Character is not valid.
```

FYI, `Textbox6` is the cells where this expression resides. Any help in correcting this expression would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two Problems with your diff expression.
First i would take away some equal signs:

```
=IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!AP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, 0) – IIf(Fields!ACCOUNTING_PERIOD.Value = Parameters!PRAP.Value, Fields!DEPR.Value, 0)
```

The second thing is, that according to the error message your Fields seem to formatted as characters not doubles. So you will need to convert them before substracting them. You should already do this in your sql-code with:

```
CONVERT(Fields!DEPR.Value AS numeric)
```

Hope this helps